# any data i can use for healthcare fraud detection

Tags: dataset, fraud-detection

I am truly desperate in looking for a healthcare fraud data for my project on fraud detection. Can some kind soul please please help me? I have searched online but found nothing..May i know where to get such data?
Many many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you asking for an actual dataset?  Or about methods used to detect fraud?  I think it will be exceedingly difficult to get your hands on an actual dataset, as patient confidentiality is critical.  Have you tried some competition websites like kaggle or topcoder?  They may have datasets from past competitions that you could download.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Files-for-Order/IdentifiableDataFiles/StandardAnalyticalFiles.html)?

Comment: This could be a nice source http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Asking for datasets is off-topic here. See the above suggestion for a more appropriate place.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the healthcare data (emergency room entrants) ; 24 hours for 884 consecutive days
[Seasonality in residuals ACF and PACF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248433/seasonality-in-residuals-acf-and-pacf/248661#248661) and manipulate it to incorporate fraudulent activity like false excessive values. In this way you can detect the anomalies that might be hidden to the "eye" thus exposing POSSIBLE fraud or at least some exceptional activity. I have the real-world data and will be glad to share it with you.