# Semi-Hidden Markov Model with parameters of the emission probabilities depending on regressors

Tags: r, regression, time-series, hidden-markov-model, latent-variable

I'm trying to implement a **Hidden Markov Model** to detect past stockouts in sales 
(a stockout is when the retailer runs out of a product). It's probably better to say a ***Semi***-**Hidden Markov Model**, let me explain it. 
Let's say I have a year of hourly data about sales of a product in a retailer.

**VARIABLES IN THE MODEL:**

- $Y_t \in Z^+$, number of items sold at time t.
- Latent states $X_t \in  \big\{0,1\big\}$,with 
  $0$ indicating the inavailability of the product due to stockout, $1$ the availabilty of it.

So I have $n=2$ latent states and have $m_1 \in Z^+$, so a $\infty$ number of possible observation symbols for state 1 (all the positive Integers) , while $m_0= 0 $ (only observable symbol is 0 when I have no product left). Actually I could choose to set the observable symbols for state $1 \in \big\{sale / nosale\big\}$   , to simplify the model and have a finite number of observation symbols for state $1$.

**PARAMETERS OF THE MODEL:**

- the initial probability $P(X_0)$ distribution,  (I can set the start of the series with a sale, so that $P(X_0=1)=1$. )
- the state transition probability matrix $P(X_{t+1}=j|X_t=i), i,j \in  \big\{0,1\big\}$ (*Here I consider a first order HMM,but it's not a must*)
- the emission
  probability $P(Y_t=m|X_t=i), m \in Z^+,i,j \in \big\{0,1\big\}$.

Furthermore I know that $P(Y_t=m|X_t=0)=0 $
                  $\forall m \ne 0$,  since I cannot observe sales of a product not available and that could be an added helpful constraint on the sequence of states I wish to find, for example:

$Y_t=0,Y_{t+1}=3,Y_{t+2}=1,Y_{t+3}=0,\dots$ makes me impose: 
$X_t \in \big\{0,1\big\}, X_{t+1}=1, X_{t+2}=1, X_{t+3} \in \big\{0,1\big\},\dots$

**I ALSO HAVE A SET OF REGRESSORS (hour of the day, day of the week, promotions and prices of the other products,ecc.) and I was thinking about a linear/poisson distribution given the set of regressors**(think about this: there's a huge promotion for another product and I get 0 sales for the product of interest even if it is available, so I'd like to use this further information) for 
$P(Y_t=m|X_t=1) = Z_t*\beta $ where $Z_t$ is the set of regressors at time $t$ and $\beta$ are the OLS regression coefficients estimates. That's an idea, I could also just say that: $Y_t|X_t=1 \sim Poi(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ I wish to estimate.

***I ask for help in further building the model and some advice on how to implement in R/Python***, I know the depmix function in package depmixS4, but it doesn't support different observations probability distributions (One way to face that was to consider the daily data, not the hourly ones. In that case, since the retailer has a daily restock of the stocked-out items the emission probabilities when the latent state is $0$ (which in the daily case would represent the event "*A stockout has occurred in that day/the item is not available in that day*"

$P(Y_t=m|X_t=0) >= 0 $   because I could have that the retailer ran out of a product at some point during a day after selling some items of it.
In that case I could use a Poisson for both the observations probabilities, but one will be zero-inflated, while the other not.

I don't have deep knowledge about HMM, even if I already worked with Markov Chains and Conditional Distributions/Omitted Variables in Bayesian and Applied Stats. My main reference was [hmm_fundamentals](http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-hmm.pdf)

**EDIT**:

I want to stress the fact that I would like to exploit the information regarding the regressors, so that, when the Hidden State is $X_t=1$=*product available*, the Observation distribution Probability $f(Y_t|X_t=1)$ follows a $Poi(\lambda_t)$, where $\lambda_t= Z_t*\beta_{OLS}$, with $Z_t$ indicating the set of regressors at time $t$.

**EDIT 2**:

I noticed on the data that some usually high selling products may not have a clear stockout, let me explain it:

[image: Hourly sales of a particular product]

And then, higlighting the 11th-18th of October week:

[image: Detail of the procut above]

As you can see there is quite a long period in which the product is rarely selling and furthermore when it sells it is well under its usual behaviour (I used this 3 months period, but its usual behaviour is confirmed over a longer period). 
I interpreted this as: there are a few items left (maybe old stocked items in storage) and time passes by before another replenishment. In this case the problem would change, since:

$P(Y_t>0|X_t=0) \geq 0$ and the problem would be purely Hidden-Markov Model (no known latent states in the sequence).

Comment: You could fit parameters using the EM algorithm and baum-welch.  See https://www.princeton.edu/~rvan/orf557/hmm080728.pdf.

Comment: @Adrian good Lord that's a heck of a reference, thank you.. I hope I can find a more straightforward approach tough..

Comment: Have a look at Algorithm 6.1: Concrete EM Algorithm/Proposition 6.11 and Algorithm 3.2: Baum-Welch Algorithm -- you only need slight modifications to apply those to your problem

Comment: If working with HMMs for the first time you should also go through the [classic tutorial by Rabiner](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf)

Comment: Thanks ! I'm reading it right now.. 

By the way: @bdeonovic  and Adrian, do you think the question is sufficiently clear?

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini the setup was a bit confusing at first, but after reading through it all I think the question is clear. I'm not familiar with the R packages for HMMs, but this seems like a relatively straight forward HMM problem so I would be surprised if you couldn't fit it with something off the shelf. However, this sounds like it would be a good experience to program the Baum-welch algorithm yourself

Comment: Some thoughts: if $m_1$ and $m_0$ are the number of observable states for $Y_t$ given $X_t=1$ and $X_t=0$ respectively, then $m_0$ should be 1 ($Y_t$ can only take on 1 state, that is $Y_t=0$ when $X_t=0$). I've made the appropriate edits, make sure it still says what you want it to say.

Comment: @bdeonovic Thank you! I corrected your edit, as you said it wasn't clear before: with one $m_1$ I referred to the cardinality of the set of observable symbols and with $m_0$ to the observable symbols. Now they both refer to the set of observable symbols given the latent states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some quick R code to get you started.  Major caveats:  I wrote this myself, so it could be buggy, statistically incorrect, poorly styled... use at your own risk!

```
params_are_valid <- function(params) {
    stopifnot("lambdas" %in% names(params))   # Poisson parameters for each hidden state
    stopifnot(all(params$lambas >= 0.0))
    stopifnot(length(params$lambdas) == params$n_hidden_states)
    stopifnot("mu" %in% names(params))  # Initial distribution over hidden states
    stopifnot(length(params$mu) == params$n_hidden_states)
    stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(sum(params$mu), 1.0)))  # Probabilities sum to 1
    stopifnot(all(params$mu >= 0.0))
    stopifnot("P" %in% names(params))  # Transition probabilities for hidden state
    stopifnot(nrow(params$P) == params$n_hidden_states && ncol(params$P) == params$n_hidden_states)
    stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(rowSums(params$P), rep(1, params$n_hidden_states))))  # Probabilities sum to 1
    stopifnot(all(params$P >= 0))
    return(TRUE)
}

baum_welch_poisson <- function(observed_y, params) {
    ## Baum-Welch algorithm for HMM with discrete hidden x
    ## Discrete observations y (NAs allowed) with y|x ~ Poisson(params$lambdas[x])
    ## Written following Ramon van Handel's HMM notes, page 40, algorithm 3.2
    ## https://www.princeton.edu/~rvan/orf557/hmm080728.pdf
    ## Careful, his observation index is in {0, 1, ... , n} while I use {1, 2, ... , length(observed_y)}
    y_length <- length(observed_y)
    stopifnot(y_length > 1)
    stopifnot(all(observed_y >= 0 | is.na(observed_y)))
    stopifnot(all(observed_y %% 1 == 0 | is.na(observed_y)))  # Integer observations
    stopifnot(params_are_valid(params))
    c <- vector("numeric", y_length)
    if(is.na(observed_y[1])) {
        upsilon <- rep(1, params$n_hidden_states)
    } else {
        upsilon <- dpois(observed_y[1], lambda=params$lambdas)
    }
    stopifnot(length(upsilon) == params$n_hidden_states)
    c[1] <- sum(upsilon * params$mu)
    ## Matrix pi_contemporaneous gives probabilities over x_k conditional on {y_1, y_2, ... , y_k}
    ## Notation in van Handel's HMM notes is pi_k, whereas pi_{k|n} conditions on full history of y
    pi_contemporaneous <- matrix(NA, params$n_hidden_states, y_length)
    pi_contemporaneous[, 1] <- upsilon * params$mu / c[1]
    upsilon_list <- list()
    upsilon_list[[1]] <- upsilon
    for(k in seq(2, y_length)) {
        ## Forward loop
        if(is.na(observed_y[k])) {
            upsilon <- rep(1, params$n_hidden_states)
        } else {
            upsilon <- dpois(observed_y[k], lambda=params$lambdas)
        }
        upsilon_list[[k]] <- upsilon  # Cache for backward loop
        pi_tilde <- upsilon * t(params$P) %*% pi_contemporaneous[, k-1]
        c[k] <- sum(pi_tilde)
        pi_contemporaneous[, k] <- pi_tilde  / c[k]
    }
    beta <- matrix(NA, params$n_hidden_states, y_length)
    beta[, y_length] <- 1 / c[y_length]
    ## Matrix pi gives probabilities over x conditional on full history of y
    ## Notation in van Handel's HMM notes is pi_{k|n}, as opposed to pi_k
    pi <- matrix(NA, params$n_hidden_states, y_length)
    pi[, y_length] <- pi_contemporaneous[, y_length]
    pi_transition_list <- list()  # List of posterior probabilities over hidden x transitions
    for(k in seq(1, y_length - 1)) {
        ## Backward loop
        upsilon <- diag(upsilon_list[[y_length - k + 1]], params$n_hidden_states, params$n_hidden_states)
        pi_matrix <- diag(pi_contemporaneous[, y_length - k],
                          params$n_hidden_states, params$n_hidden_states)
        beta_matrix <- diag(beta[, y_length - k + 1], params$n_hidden_states, params$n_hidden_states)
        beta[, y_length - k] <- params$P %*% upsilon %*% beta[, y_length - k + 1] / c[y_length - k]
        pi_transition_list[[y_length - k]] <- pi_matrix %*% params$P %*% upsilon %*% beta_matrix
        stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(sum(pi_transition_list[[y_length - k]]), 1.0)))
        pi[, y_length - k] <- rowSums(pi_transition_list[[y_length - k]])
    }
    loglik <- sum(log(c))
    return(list(loglik=loglik, pi=pi, pi_transition_list=pi_transition_list))
}

## Notice that params0$lambas is zero for first hidden state, i.e. first hidden state represents a stockout
params0 <- list("n_hidden_states"=2,
                "mu"=c(0.10, 0.90),  # Initial distribution over hidden states
                "P"=rbind(c(0.50, 0.50),
                          c(0.10, 0.90)),  # Transition probabilities for hidden state
                "lambdas"=c(0, 2))  # Observe y|x ~ Poisson(lambdas[x])

observations <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 5, 6, 7, NA, 5, 8, 9, 0, 6)
bw_list <- baum_welch_poisson(observations, params0)

round(bw_list$pi, 3)  # Posterior probabilities over hidden states given observations (first row is stockout state)
bw_list$pi[, which(observations != 0)]  # Sanity check: we're certain we're in hidden state 2 whenever observations > 0
bw_list$pi[, which(observations == 0 |
                   is.na(observations))]  # When observations are zero (or NA), we could be in either state
```

The code runs Baum-Welch on a simple two-state HMM with Poisson observations.  In this case, I set the poisson rate (lambda) to be zero for the first hidden state (and positive for the second hidden state), which makes the first hidden state a "stockout" state as in your example.

The example does not actually fit parameters (estimate them from data) -- for that you would need to write e.g. an expectation-maximization (EM) function.

Comment: Thank you! I will study the code and run it before ticking the answer :)

Comment: How would you modify your code in order to have a time dependent $\lambda_t=Z_t*\beta$ ?

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini remove `params$lambas` and replace it with e.g. `params$beta`, a coefficient matrix with n_hidden_states rows and as many columns as you have covariates.  In the calls to `dpois`, replace `params$lambas` with `params$beta %*% your_covariate_vector[appropriate_time_subscript]`.  You'd have to add `your_covariate_vector` as an argument to the baum_welch function.

Comment: I was sloppy above about your covariates:  since they're time-varying, you might store them in a time-by-number_of_covariates matrix, in which case your lambas would be something like `params$beta %*% your_covariate_matrix[appropriate_time_subscript, ]`, which would produce a vector of lambas of length n_hidden_states.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I ticked your answer. Unfortunately I'd like to both estimate the regression parameters while running Baum-Welch and impose a set of latent states as known.. 

for now I train the regression coefficients and then impute them as fixed.. 

Thank you again :) !

Comment: @Adrian sorry I'm joining this conversation too late maybe but I'm working on using HMM to anomaly detection. Given your last statement the dimension of the matrix is wrong, isn't? If we have $\beta$ n_hidden_state*no_covariates and $Z_{t}$ as a time by covariates matrix the multiplication $Z_{t}$*$\beta$ can't be right, am I wrong?